# How to build current project only in Eclipse CDT on "Build project"?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am working with Eclipse CDT and I want to build the current project only, not any referenced project. Is this somehow possible?

The idea behind this is, that I want to distinguish between "Build Project" and "Build all projects" (in which case, referenced libraries should be built as well).

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: Not possible atm, but there is an open bug for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644138/how-to-build-current-project-only-in-eclipse-cdt-on-build-project

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev your comment links back to this question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd love to have a better answer for this - the only workaround I know of is to go and actually close all the projects but the one you want built.

Comment: Yes, but as you say, it is a "weak" workaround, as in this case code-completion won't work as well. What a pity that this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: @Martin C. - it's not just weak, it's a complete nuisance. I'd love to be able to have a couple of small utilities as side projects to a rather large application project, but every build of a small util incurs the full rebuild on the large project. Closing and opening projects all the time is just about impractical.

Comment: This does not work in recent eclipse versions. It will throw an error about referenced projects being open.

Answer (score 32):

I use another workaround; I changed the default key binding for "Build All" to Alt+Ctrl+B, and changed the binding to "Build Project" to "Ctrl+B".

If you didn't want to mess with the defaults you could add the custom binding (e.g., Alt+Ctrl+B directly to "Build Project".

To change keyboard shortcuts go to &Window, &Preferences, and search for "keys".

Comment: the only helpful ans :)

Comment: Thanks, been searching around for a soln for a long time before finding this

Comment: In my case, I have things referenced and a "Build Project" still builds the referenced projects :-/

Answer (score 9):

**Shortcut Key Method**

Another way is to change the shortcut key for building a project eg. Ctrl-B to only Build Project, instead of Build All.

1. Go to Window -> Preferences
2. In General -> Keys, find "Build" in the filter
3. There are two cases, Build All and Build Project.
4. Personally, I set Ctrl-B to Build Project by pressing Ctrl-B in the Binding Box
5. Next I set Ctrl-A Ctrl-B sequence to build all Projects

Try it out

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the project explorer and choose `"Build Project"`, or
just use the:

```
"Project" menu -> "Build Project"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that 'Build Project' is grayed (disabled) in the Project menu (and not in the Project Explorer context menu) when the Project -> 'Build Automatically' option is checked.  I unchecked that and can now independently build my projects.

Comment: Hi, of course you need to disable "Build Automatically", still if you select "Build Project" (Ctrl-B), it will automatically build all dependencies of the project as well. That's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I un-reference the projects. Somehow the newest CDT is still able to find things in the code.

Build only the project dindn't work as it would still build all.